Equivalent conditions for $z$-embeddability
I am looking for where this specific theorem of Blair is originally located:
Theorem. Let $S\subseteq X$, the following are equivalent:

$S$ is $z$-embedded

If $A, B\subseteq S$ are disjoint zero-sets of $S$ then $A\subseteq Z$ and $Z\cap B = \emptyset$ for some zero-set $Z$ of $X$

If $A, B\subseteq S$ are completely separated, then $A, B$ are $S$-separated.


Here the last condition means that there exist zero-sets $Z, Z'$ of $X$ such that $A\subseteq Z, B\subseteq Z'$ and $Z\cap Z'\cap S = \emptyset$.
This theorem is from Normal topological spaces by Alo and Shapiro. I was searching in Extensions of Zero-sets and of Real-valued Functions. by Blair and Hager but its not there.
The book Normal topological spaces tells me its in Mappings that preserve realcompactness by Blair, but I couldn't find it there.

The equivalence of 1 and 3 can be found in [https://doi.org/10.4064/fm-90-3-285-300](Filter characterizations of z-, C*-, and C-embeddings) by Blair but, as he mentions there, it was proved earlier by Alò, Imler and Shapiro in [https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01435410](P- and z-embedded subspaces).
